# How can I check if a variable is less then a certain number in ejs

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I have the following code

```
<%if (locals.average > 4.5 && locals.average < 5){%>
              <div>test</div>
<%}%>
```

If i apply the following code the test div doesnot appear I think the problem is with less than 5 because if I use this only

```
<%if (locals.average > 4.5){%>
              <div>test</div>
<%}%>
```

It works fine. How can I use less than symbol in ejs

Comment: What is the actual value of `locals.average` when you experience this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ejs - but assuming your parser is tripping-up on `<` (e.g. thinking it's the start of a tag) then use the logical inverse of `less-than` (which is `not-greater-than-or-equal-to`):

```
<% if( locals.average > 4.5 && !( locals.average >= 5 ) ) { %>
              <div>test</div>
<% } %>
```

That said, the documentation for ejs suggests that your original code *should* work - as it's just a normal JavaScript expression. If you find out why it really didn't work you should post that as the answer and accept that answer instead of mine.